# Can I use the graphing library 'plotly' on my website?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I am looking to use plotly on my website. It says open - source. Does this mean I can use it on my website free of charge or does it simply mean I can only use it as a development tool but must remove it when actually releasing the website (or replace it with something such as d3)?

Comment: Just to clarify I have done the code myself and I am using plotly's js.

Comment: plotly/dash is licensed under the MIT License:
"A short and simple permissive license with conditions only requiring preservation of copyright and license notices. Licensed works, modifications, and larger works may be distributed under different terms and without source code."

Notice that this question does not belong to Stackoverflow, which is for solving coding problem, not licensing issues.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am relatively new to the coding world and don't really knows the do's and don'ts. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick google search. This statement is from [plotly.com](https://plotly.com/javascript/is-plotly-free/).

[image]